# Set settlement spawn point

Tags: fallout-4

I remember being able to choose where I land in my settlement, when I fast travel. It was something like a carpet I could place on the ground (in the workshop-mode).
I can't find that now. Did they patch it out? Or where can I find this option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fast-travel target mat should be under *Resources > Miscellaneous > Fast Travel Target* in the workshop menu.

Comment: Just did it! Thanks :)
Kinda embarrassing that I didn't find it myself. Thought it may be harder to achieve.